# AndroidHttpClient and DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, android

Is there much difference between those two and which one is preferably to use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`AndroidHttpClient`: Subclass of the Apache `DefaultHttpClient` that is configured with reasonable default settings and registered schemes for Android, and also lets the user add `HttpRequestInterceptor` classes.
This client processes cookies but does not retain them by default. To retain cookies, simply add a cookie store to the `HttpContext`

[[API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html)]

Comment: To be fair, this isn't totally true.. If you look at the documentation closely, its not a subclass.. I believe the AndroidHttpClient internally uses the DefaultHttpClient as a delegate but does not expose any of its public methods (besides those in the interface to begin with)..

Comment: The `AndroidHttpClient` internally uses the `DefaultHttpClient`.

Comment: This is what the documentation says, but it still leaves the casual observer bereft of further details on "reasonable default settings".

Comment: it's not a subclass, which doesn't seems very clever because you can't  easily write code that work on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 28):

Based on the Android source code:

https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread/core/java/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.java#L106

AndroidHttpClient is set to do the following extra settings:

1. Turn off stale checking, since the connections can break all the time.
2. Set ConnectionTimeout and SoTimeout (20 or 60 seconds)
3. Turn off redirecting.
4. Use a session cache for SSL sockets.
5. Use gzip compressed traffic between client and server if it's possible.
6. Doesn't retain cookies by default.

Answer (score 3):

This interesting  [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)  from an android developer gives an overview of the different Android’s HTTP clients.

According to this post,  [URLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html)  should be preferred over DefaultHttpClient or AndroidHttpClient on Gingerbread and above.