# Android: AndroidHttpClient - how to set timeout?

Tags: java, android, http, networking, timeout

I have followed the instructions of [kuester2000's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693997/how-to-set-httpresponse-timeout-for-android-in-java), but my timeout settings don't seem to work.

```
try
{
    int timeout = 3000;
    URL myURL = //some valid URL

    AndroidHttpClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("name");
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(myURL.toExternalForm());

    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, timeout);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeout);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

    //...
}
catch (SocketTimeoutException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (ConnectTimeoutException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//...
```

However, the timeout value doesn't change anything.

In the answer I linked, it also says:

> The connection timeout throws "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket is not connected" and the socket timeout "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: The operation timed out".

But I get neither. Instead I get "org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to ... timed out"

so can anybody help me? where is the mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *did* miss to attach the params to my http request, but the proper way to do this in my example is

```
httpGet.setParams(httpParams);
```

before calling httpClient.execute(httpGet).

Just added that line and it worked fine.

Answer (score 9):

You do not use the `httpParams` params, they must be provided to the HTTPClient. So it won't work like this. In the anwer you linked, the order is correct!  Try the following order: Create the Params first and supply them to the HTTPClient.

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

Comment: I just realized thanks to your answer that I forgot to insert httpClient.setParams(httpParameters);, which was suggested by kuester2000. However, it's not working with AndroidHttpClient.
Is it possible to use AndroidHttpClient instead of HttpClient the way you do?

Comment: Do you really need the features of AndroidHTTPClient? Otherwise you could simply use DefaultHTTPClient.

Comment: actually, I don't really know the difference... this probably means "no", doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, perhaps, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135918/androidhttpclient-and-defaulthttpclient

Comment: I did get that far, but "reasonable default settings" is not really helpful to me. ^^ However, it says in the documentation at the "newInstance" method: "Create a new HttpClient with reasonable defaults (which you can update)." but I can't find a way to update them.

Comment: You have to choose: Either you let Android choose the defaults (including the timouts), or set the settings yourself. If you realy need configurable timeouts, then take the DefaultHTTPClient.

Comment: solved it by adding one simple line, but as you hinted out what was wrong initially, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 5):

The other option to set on the client itself:

```
AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Client V/1.0");
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(this.client.getParams(), 3000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(this.client.getParams(), 5000);
```

This should result in those particular params being set...

HTH

Comment: I like that. Here's a more detailed explanation: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Android-DefaultHttpClientAndroidHttpClient-and-HttpParams.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After reading around, here's how I did it using the params straight from the default client:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpParams params = client.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 3000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 3000);
```

Original credit goes to http://www.jayway.com/2009/03/17/configuring-timeout-with-apache-httpclient-40/