# How can i Handle special kind of exception in doinBackground() method

Tags: android, exception, android-asynctask

I am making an android app which requires it to fetch some information from a remote server and therefore i have to make a http request in a async task.Now the problem is that that the response sometimes take more than 2 secs and when it does it give http timeout exception but most of the time it works just fine .So i want to implement the functionality that when i recieve a http timeout exception i want to retry the request again(try the doinBackground again,because network call can only be made in thread other than the main thread) because chances are that it will be successful and all the things that need to be fetched from the remote server will occur in `CallRemoteServer()` method

Now in my program i have implemented something like this

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
private boolean httpResponseOK = true; 
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {

                CallRemoteServer();
                }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    httpResponseOK = false;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                if (httpResponseOK == false) {

        //Show an alert dialog stating that unable to coonect
                                        }
else
{
     //update UI with the information fetched
}
                                    });
```

Can someone advice me how can i implement something which i have mentioned above ,i mean that if i get some other exception other than timeout than show an alert dialog otherwise retry atleast five time more CallRemoteServer method before showing the dialog that unable to connect.

I am not able to think of any good way to implement this logic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: in the `doInBackground()` method, catch the error and set a flag, which to be sent back to the `Activity`, from where you call the `AsyncTask`. If the flag is set - then re-try the `AsyncClass.execute()`.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you looping in the `doInBackground` method of an `AsyncTask`. Just use an `int` to count the loops and have a `boolean` set to check in a `while` loop. If the `int` gets to more than 4 or the `boolean` is set to `true` (for a successful result) then the `while` loop should exit.

Comment: @Squonk if i use a while loop and a simple counter logic than once i get an exception it will exit and go to catch(Exception e) line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting a [`ConnectTimeoutException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ConnectTimeoutException.html) (or check in the logs what is the `IOException` you're getting). I would first try to extend the timeout. Some similar answers for this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693997/how-to-set-httpresponse-timeout-for-android-in-java) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730078/android-androidhttpclient-how-to-set-timeout).

However, an auto-reconnect mechanism is a must to have. I would implement it using recursive code:

```
final int maxAttempts = 5;
protected MyServerData callRemoteServer(int attempt) throws IOException {
    try {
        // do the IO stuff and in case of success return some data
    } catch (ConnectTimeoutException ex) {
        if(attempt == maxAttempts) {
            return callRemoteServer(attempt + 1);
        } else {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Your `doInBackground` method should look like:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {

        callRemoteServer(0);
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}
```

In this way if the connection timeouts it will attempt to retry for 5 max times (you can set the max attempts to anything you like). Just make sure to return some data from this IO operation as that is the most valuable asset from that method anyway ...

For this reason I would change it to following:

```
private class MyAsynckTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MyServerData> {

    @Override
    protected MyServerData doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            return callRemoteServer(0);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(MyServerData result) {
        if(result != null) {
            // display data on UI
        }
    }
}
```